# Duplicate tags about duplicate files

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

- [deduplication](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deduplication)
- [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/duplicate) seems to be used for deduplication but some are about how to create duplicate files.
- [duplicate-files](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-files)
- [duplicating](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/duplicating)

I suggest merging into [deduplication](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/deduplication) for most of those questions.

Comment: I'd merge `duplicate-files` and `duplicating` → `duplicate`. "Deduplication" … doesn't sound too obvious, and the "duplicate" tag will certainly be recreated unless synonimized.

Comment: [tag:duplicate] is quite messed up. I was thinking of merging [tag:duplicate-files] into [tag:duplicate] but looking at [tag:duplicate] questions, not too sure if that's wise.  // @slhck

Comment: Okay, didn't really look into the questions specifically @sat

Comment: @slhck  There's also some foundational differences between between deduplication (typically done by a filesystem, automatically) and "find duplicates" for purposes of removal, linking, whatever.  Sometimes talking about finding and deleting duplicates turns into a deduplication discussion, but not often the other way.